# Heap selection sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, sorting, heap, heap-sort

I have (designed and) implemented this fancy sorting algorithm that combines natural runs in the input array with a heap data structure:

```
function ArrayRangeException(message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.getMessage = function() { return this.message; }
}

function RangeCheck(arrayLength, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    if (fromIndex < 0) {
        throw new ArrayRangeException("'fromIndex' is negative: " + fromIndex);
    }

    if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
        throw new ArrayRangeException(
                "'toIndex' is too large: " + toIndex + ", array length: " + 
                arrayLength);
    }

    if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
        throw new ArrayRangeException(
            "fromIndex(" + fromIndex + ") > toIndex(" + toIndex + ")");
    }
}   

function RunHeap(array, cmp) {
    this.cmp = cmp;
    this.array = array;
    const auxArrayLength = (array.length >>> 1) + 1;
    this.fromIndexArray = Array(auxArrayLength);
    this.toIndexArray = Array(auxArrayLength);
    this.size = 0;

    this.pushRun = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
        const nodeIndex = this.size++;
        this.fromIndexArray[nodeIndex] = fromIndex;
        this.toIndexArray[nodeIndex] = toIndex;
    },

    this.popElement = function() {
        const returnValue = this.array[this.fromIndexArray[0]];
        this.fromIndexArray[0]++;

        if (this.fromIndexArray[0] === this.toIndexArray[0]) {
            const last1 = this.fromIndexArray[--this.size];
            this.fromIndexArray[0] = last1;

            const last2 = this.toIndexArray[this.size];
            this.toIndexArray[0] = last2;
        }

        this.siftDown(0);
        return returnValue;
    },

    this.swap = function(array, index1, index2) {
        const tmp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = tmp;
    },

    this.isLessThan = function(runIndex1, runIndex2) {
        const element1 = this.array[this.fromIndexArray[runIndex1]];
        const element2 = this.array[this.fromIndexArray[runIndex2]];
        const cmp = this.cmp(element1, element2);

        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp < 0;
        }

        return this.fromIndexArray[runIndex1] < this.fromIndexArray[runIndex2];
    },

    this.siftDown = function(index) {
        let nodeIndex = index;
        let leftChildIndex = (index << 1) + 1
        let rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
        let minIndex = index;

        while (true) {
            if (leftChildIndex < this.size 
            && this.isLessThan(leftChildIndex, nodeIndex)) {
                minIndex = leftChildIndex;
            }

            if (rightChildIndex < this.size 
            && this.isLessThan(rightChildIndex, minIndex)) {
                minIndex = rightChildIndex;
            }

            if (minIndex === nodeIndex) {
                return;
            }

            this.swap(this.fromIndexArray, minIndex, nodeIndex);
            this.swap(this.toIndexArray, minIndex, nodeIndex);

            nodeIndex = minIndex;
            leftChildIndex = (nodeIndex << 1) + 1;
            rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
        }
    },

    this.buildHeap = function() {
        for (i = Math.floor(this.size / 2); i >= 0; --i) {
            this.siftDown(i);
        }
    },

    this.extendRun = function(length) {
        this.toIndexArray[this.size - 1] += length;
    },

    this.appendRun = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
        this.fromIndexArray[this.size] = fromIndex;
        this.toIndexArray[this.size] = toIndex;
        this.size++;
    }
}

function reverseRun(array, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    for (i1 = fromIndex, i2 = toIndex; i1 < i2; i1++, i2--) {
        const savedArrayComponent = array[i1];
        array[i1] = array[i2];
        array[i2] = savedArrayComponent;
    }
}

function createRunHeap(array, cmp) {
    let runHeap = new RunHeap(array, cmp);
    let left = 0;
    let right = 1;
    let last = array.length - 1;
    let previousWasDescending = false;

    while (left < last) {
        head = left;
        right = left + 1;

        if (cmp(array[left], array[right]) <= 0) {
            while (left < last && cmp(array[left], array[right]) <= 0) {
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }

            if (previousWasDescending) {
                if (cmp(array[head - 1], array[head]) <= 0) {
                    runHeap.extendRun(right - head);
                } else {
                    runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
                }
            } else {
                runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
            }

            previousWasDescending = false;
        } else { // Scan a descending run:
            while (left < last && cmp(array[left], array[right]) > 0) {
                ++left;
                ++right;
            }

            reverseRun(array, head, left);

            if (previousWasDescending) {
                if (cmp(array[head - 1], array[head]) <= 0) {
                    runHeap.extendRun(right - head);
                } else {
                    runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
                }
            } else {
                runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
            }

            previousWasDescending = true;
        }

        ++left;
        ++right;
    }

    if (left === last) {
        if (cmp(array[last - 1], array[last]) <= 0) {
            runHeap.extendRun(1);
        } else {
            runHeap.appendRun(last, last + 1);
        }
    }

    return runHeap;
}

Array.prototype.heapSelectionSort = 
function(cmp, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    if (!cmp) {
        cmp = (a, b) => a - b;
    }

    if (!fromIndex) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    }

    if (!toIndex) {
        toIndex = this.length;
    }

    RangeCheck(this.length, fromIndex, toIndex);

    if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
        return this;
    }

    const aux = this.slice(fromIndex, toIndex);
    const runHeap = createRunHeap(aux, cmp);
    runHeap.buildHeap();

    let index = fromIndex;

    while (index < toIndex) {
        this[index] = runHeap.popElement();
        index++;
    }

    return this;
};
```

(The entire demo gist is here: https://gist.github.com/coderodde/47ae57983954c89ab7bef21b3fa7b232)

**Critique request**

Since I am not a professional Javascript developer, I would like to make my code above on par with idiomatic JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible improvements:

Your `ArrayRangeException` has a `getMessage` property that is never referenced elsewhere (even if a consumer were to know about it, it would be much simpler for it to just use the `.message` property). But it's still basically just an object wrapper around a string. Since you're going to be throwing, you might consider using a built-in [RangeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError) instead, eg:

```
if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
    throw new RangeError(
        "'toIndex' is too large: " + toIndex + ', array length: ' +
        arrayLength);
}
```

You can also consider using template literals, which some consider to be more readable than concatenation:

```
if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
    throw new RangeError(`'toIndex' is too large: ${toIndex}, array length: ${arrayLength}`);
}
```

`RangeCheck` isn't a constructor, so it probably shouldn't be capitalized.

Your `RunHeap` constructor assigns lots of function properties directly to the instance, and chains them with the comma operator:

```
this.pushRun = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
  // ...
},
this.popElement = function() {
  // ...
},
this.swap = function(array, index1, index2) {
  // ...
```

The comma operator [evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). This can be [somewhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions) [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/when-is-the-comma-operator-useful), and so is often forbidden by code style guides. Since each function assignment here can be standalone, have each be a separate statement instead, and separate them with semicolons:

```
this.pushRun = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
  // ...
};
this.popElement = function() {
  // ...
};
this.swap = function(array, index1, index2) {
  // ...
```

But there's another issue - this creates those `pushRun`, `popElement`, `swap` methods anew *every time* the `RunHeap` constructor is run. This is inefficient; the functions are all the same. Put them on the prototype instead, so that they only have to be created once:

```
function RunHeap(array, cmp) {
    this.cmp = cmp;
    // ...
}
RunHeap.prototype.pushRun = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
    // ...
};

RunHeap.prototype.popElement = function() {
  // ...
```

Since you're already using ES6+ syntax (which is great, you should), it'd probably be a good idea to use it everywhere - instead of a `function` that you call `new` on, you can use `class`, they're a bit more concise and readable, and are the preferred modern way of doing things:

```
class RunHeap {
    constructor(array, cmp) {
        this.cmp = cmp;
        // ...
    }
    pushRun(fromIndex, toIndex) {
        const nodeIndex = this.size++;
        // ...
    }
    popElement() {
        const returnValue = this.array[this.fromIndexArray[0]];
        // ...
```

Using `++` / `--` as a standalone statement is fine, but they can sometimes be confusing when they're used as an expression. (This is the same idea behind avoiding [chained assignments](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-assign) and [conditional assignments](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign)) You might consider putting the increments/decrements on their own line, eg replace

```
const last1 = this.fromIndexArray[--this.size];
```

with

```
this.size--;
const last1 = this.fromIndexArray[this.size];
```

Same for the other instances of pre/post increment-as-expression.

(even if *you* find the first version readable at a glance, I wouldn't bet on most readers of the code seeing it the same way)

`if (cmp != 0) {` When comparing, best to use strict equality, [not loose equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).

`for (i = Math.floor(this.size / 2); i >= 0; --i) {` Best to always declare variables before using them - this will either implicitly create a global variable `i`, or throw an error if in strict mode. (change to `let i =`) (Same for `for (i1 = fromIndex, i2 = toIndex;` and `head = left`)

The `swap` function does the same thing as is done in each iteration of the `reverseRun` loop. Maybe have `reverseRun` call `swap`?

ES6 allows for default arguments in the case nothing is passed:

```
Array.prototype.heapSelectionSort = function (cmp, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    if (!cmp) {
        cmp = (a, b) => a - b;
    }

    if (!fromIndex) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    }

    if (!toIndex) {
        toIndex = this.length;
    }
```

can be:

```
Array.prototype.heapSelectionSort = function (
    cmp = (a, b) => a - b,
    fromIndex = 0,
    toIndex = this.length
) {
```

It's [usually a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180) to mutate the built-in objects, like `Array.prototype`. (Bad frameworks putting non-standard methods onto prototypes [is why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934491) we have `Array.prototype.flat` instead of `Array.prototype.flatten`, and `Array.prototype.includes` instead of `Array.prototype.contains`.) It can cause a few problems. You could have `heapSelectionSort` be a standalone function instead.

In full:

```js
const heapSelectionSort = (() => {
    'use strict';
    function rangeCheck(arrayLength, fromIndex, toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            throw new RangeError(`'fromIndex' is negative: ${fromIndex}`);
        }
        if (toIndex > arrayLength) {
            throw new RangeError(`'toIndex' is too large: ${toIndex}, array length: ${arrayLength}`);
        }
        if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
            throw new RangeError(`fromIndex(${fromIndex}) > toIndex(${toIndex})`);
        }
    }

    const swap = (array, index1, index2) => {
        const tmp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = tmp;
    };

    class RunHeap {
        constructor(array, cmp) {
            this.cmp = cmp;
            this.array = array;
            const auxArrayLength = (array.length >>> 1) + 1;
            this.fromIndexArray = Array(auxArrayLength);
            this.toIndexArray = Array(auxArrayLength);
            this.size = 0;
        }
        pushRun(fromIndex, toIndex) {
            this.fromIndexArray[this.size] = fromIndex;
            this.toIndexArray[this.size] = toIndex;
            this.size++;
        }
        popElement() {
            const returnValue = this.array[this.fromIndexArray[0]];
            this.fromIndexArray[0]++;

            if (this.fromIndexArray[0] === this.toIndexArray[0]) {
                this.size--;
                const last1 = this.fromIndexArray[this.size];
                this.fromIndexArray[0] = last1;

                const last2 = this.toIndexArray[this.size];
                this.toIndexArray[0] = last2;
            }

            this.siftDown(0);
            return returnValue;
        }
        isLessThan(runIndex1, runIndex2) {
            const element1 = this.array[this.fromIndexArray[runIndex1]];
            const element2 = this.array[this.fromIndexArray[runIndex2]];
            const cmp = this.cmp(element1, element2);

            if (cmp !== 0) {
                return cmp < 0;
            }

            return this.fromIndexArray[runIndex1] < this.fromIndexArray[runIndex2];
        }

        siftDown(index) {
            let nodeIndex = index;
            let leftChildIndex = (index << 1) + 1;
            let rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
            let minIndex = index;

            while (true) {
                if (leftChildIndex < this.size && this.isLessThan(leftChildIndex, nodeIndex)) {
                    minIndex = leftChildIndex;
                }

                if (rightChildIndex < this.size && this.isLessThan(rightChildIndex, minIndex)) {
                    minIndex = rightChildIndex;
                }

                if (minIndex === nodeIndex) {
                    return;
                }

                swap(this.fromIndexArray, minIndex, nodeIndex);
                swap(this.toIndexArray, minIndex, nodeIndex);

                nodeIndex = minIndex;
                leftChildIndex = (nodeIndex << 1) + 1;
                rightChildIndex = leftChildIndex + 1;
            }
        }

        buildHeap() {
            for (let i = Math.floor(this.size / 2); i >= 0; i--) {
                this.siftDown(i);
            }
        }

        extendRun(length) {
            this.toIndexArray[this.size - 1] += length;
        }

        appendRun(fromIndex, toIndex) {
            this.fromIndexArray[this.size] = fromIndex;
            this.toIndexArray[this.size] = toIndex;
            this.size++;
        }
    }

    function reverseRun(array, fromIndex, toIndex) {
        for (let i1 = fromIndex, i2 = toIndex; i1 < i2; i1++ , i2--) {
            swap(array, i1, i2);
        }
    }

    function createRunHeap(array, cmp) {
        const runHeap = new RunHeap(array, cmp);
        let left = 0;
        let right = 1;
        const last = array.length - 1;
        let previousWasDescending = false;

        while (left < last) {
            const head = left;
            right = left + 1;

            if (cmp(array[left], array[right]) <= 0) {
                while (left < last && cmp(array[left], array[right]) <= 0) {
                    left++;
                    right++;
                }

                if (previousWasDescending) {
                    if (cmp(array[head - 1], array[head]) <= 0) {
                        runHeap.extendRun(right - head);
                    } else {
                        runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
                    }
                } else {
                    runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
                }

                previousWasDescending = false;
            } else { // Scan a descending run:
                while (left < last && cmp(array[left], array[right]) > 0) {
                    left++;
                    right++;
                }

                reverseRun(array, head, left);

                if (previousWasDescending) {
                    if (cmp(array[head - 1], array[head]) <= 0) {
                        runHeap.extendRun(right - head);
                    } else {
                        runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
                    }
                } else {
                    runHeap.appendRun(head, right);
                }

                previousWasDescending = true;
            }

            left++;
            right++;
        }

        if (left === last) {
            if (cmp(array[last - 1], array[last]) <= 0) {
                runHeap.extendRun(1);
            } else {
                runHeap.appendRun(last, last + 1);
            }
        }

        return runHeap;
    }

    return (
        arr,
        cmp = (a, b) => a - b,
        fromIndex = 0,
        toIndex = arr.length
    ) => {
        rangeCheck(arr.length, fromIndex, toIndex);

        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return arr;
        }

        const aux = arr.slice(fromIndex, toIndex);
        const runHeap = createRunHeap(aux, cmp);
        runHeap.buildHeap();

        let index = fromIndex;

        while (index < toIndex) {
            arr[index] = runHeap.popElement();
            index++;
        }

        return arr;
    };
})();

console.log(
  heapSelectionSort([4, 5, 0, 1, 7, 8])
);
```